# Combine AND OR and NOT?

Tags: sql

I seem to be stuck searching for a solution:

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    c.CompanyName AS Kunde, 
    c.IsActiveClient AS "Aktiv i CV", 
    c.ssn AS CVR, cf.CustomFieldDefinitionFk, 
    cf.Value
FROM 
    Person AS c
INNER JOIN 
    CustomFields AS cf ON  c.Id = cf.PersonFk
WHERE 
    cf.Value = 'Visma'
ORDER BY 
    Kunde;
```

This works fine I get this output:

[image: List]

But in the same column (customFields->Value) I have some "kunde/Customers" that I want to exclude from my list.

They have both Visma and the "1850..." in "Value" (in 2 rows)

But if they have the "1850" row, they should not be in my list at all even though they have the "Visma" Value.

I have tried a lot of NOT like and other basics. No luck.

[image: Visma value]

[image: 1850... to be excluded if it has this line]

Comment: In your sample data it's not clear that the same PersonFk has both values in different rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT
  c.CompanyName AS Kunde, c.IsActiveClient AS "Aktiv i CV", c.ssn AS CVR, 
  cf.CustomFieldDefinitionFk, cf.Value
FROM Person AS c INNER JOIN CustomFields AS cf 
ON  c.Id = cf.PersonFk
WHERE cf.Value = 'Visma'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM CustomFields
  WHERE PersonFk = cf.PersonFk AND Value LIKE '1850%'
)
ORDER BY Kunde;
```